# Make a phone call from Cisco Jabber using .Net console app

Tags: c#, xmpp, cisco

I am trying to make a phone call from .Net console Application using Jabber client installed on my laptop.

I want to achieve something similar that you would achieve by the following anchor command in HTML:

```
<a href="CISCOTELCONF:msmith@domain;amckenzi@domain">Weekly conference call</a>
```

I want to run the same command through my console application so that it launches Jabber and make a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Jabber, but most likely the client has registered the `CISCOTELCONF` protocol (similar to how `HTTP` is registered to your default browser and `MAILTO` might open Outlook). Therefore you should be able to use `Process.Start` to pass the same URL to the shell, where it can decide what to do - hopefully invoking the Jabber client as it would if you clicked on the link. You can test this by copy-and-pasting the URL into Start-Run. If it works, then this should also.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CISCOTELCONF:msmith@domain;amckenzi@domain")
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Note the default for `UseShellExecute` is true, so you do not actually need this line. I've included it anyway because this is what causes `Process.Start` to, well, invoke the OS shell.